# How important is zooming in and out (cmd + , cmd - ) for websites (Desktop view) in terms of accessibility?

Tags: accessibility, css, zooming

I am working on a website at the moment and someone else is in charge of the HTML/CSS side of things.

I've noticed it's not possible to zoom in and out with the browser function of <kbd>cmd</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd>. The website just rescales instantly due to the css.

I don't know how important this feature is in terms of accessibility. Do people with strong impairments of vision use it regularly or are there other use cases I am not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

Browser zoom is probably the most used accessibility feature. Also make sure pinch to zoom works on a mobile as that is used even more.

### Long Answer

Lost of people use browser zoom to some extent.

They may not necessarily be disabled.

For example I am currently viewing this site at 150% zoom. This is due to having a 40" 4k monitor monitor positioned about a meter away. I have no disabilities but without being able to zoom this site the text would be too small to read.

More importantly - the [Web Aim low vision survey shows around 44% of assistive technology users use the browser zoom settings.](https://webaim.org/projects/lowvisionsurvey2/#at)

#### Web aim survey screenshot

[image: screenshot of webaim survery highlighting 44% of users responded that they use browser zoom as an accessibility feature]

#### How import is zooming in and out (cmd + , cmd - ) for websites (Desktop view) in terms of accessibility?

"very".

It is **very** important to allow users to zoom into your site.

I would normally cite WCAG rules here ([1.4.4 resize text](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/resize-text.html), [1.4.10 reflow](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/reflow.html)) but I think that would be unnecessary ;-) and instead say that common sense says allow zooming on your site.

Comment: great, thank you for your reply!

Comment: not a problem, glad it helped.